# Can i replace HAVE with ARE?

Tags: word-choice

This is film critic Robbie Collin for The Telegraph:

> Whether *Listen Up Philip* is a significant step up for Perry or just business as usual, I can’t tell you: his previous two features, *Impolex* and *The Colour Wheel*, **have** yet to be released in the UK.

What difference would it make if *have* is replaced with *are* ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Have to be" or "are to be": difference in meaning?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288200/have-to-be-or-are-to-be-difference-in-meaning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> his previous two features, Impolex and The Colour Wheel, have yet to be released in the UK.

This can be simplified to “They have yet to be released.”

**They *have yet to be* released.** This is the causative passive – **the arrangements for their release** have not been made yet (by someone)  -> Someone has not yet made arrangements for their release.

**They *are yet* to be released** – This is the passive – they have not yet been released (by someone) – Someone has not yet released them.

Comment: Thanks, @Greybeard. Could you please help me understand this sentence (from the same article) as well? : *Philip is a low-flying gargoyle on the New York literary scene whose second novel may be about to lift him to more rarefied altitudes*.

Comment: @Pkjmm That is a new question and requires a new post...

Comment: Basically the part that troubles me is the part *low-flying gargoyle*. I cannot make any sense of it.

Comment: Please check for duplicates. We don't want to keep re-inventing the wheelbarrow, filling ELU with bloat and mixed metaphors.

Comment: @Pkjmm - If you wish to ask about a new sentence, please start a new question.